# How do you modify "No Results Found" language in Select2 v4.0

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I attempted to use the "language.noMatches" option when initiating Select2 and its throwing an undefined function? How do I go about modifying that bit of text? I would like to include a html button that would add the input from the user if it wasn't found. I tried doing this as a function as well as plain text. I also removed all html to see if that was doing it.

```
$('#search-select').select2({

   ...

   "language": {
       "noMatches": function(){
           return "No Results Found <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>Use it anyway</a>";
       }
   }
});
```

This was previously "formatNoMatches" in Select2 v3.5

Comment: Due to a [current bug](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3202) in how translations work, you have to specify all of them under `language`.

Answer (score 146):

The option *noMatches* doesn't appear anywhere in the source code.

The actual option is named *noResults*. The working version of your example is:

```js
$('#search-select').select2({

   ...

   "language": {
       "noResults": function(){
           return "No Results Found <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>Use it anyway</a>";
       }
   },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    }
});
```

You also need to override escapeMarkup, so the button appears correctly, as per this [issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3008).

Comment: how do I get the user input and pass to noResults?
e.g 
`   "noResults": function(term){
           return term+" No found, please try another";
       }`

Comment: Note: this was IMMENSELY helpful because I didn't know how to change any messages at all. This applies to all messages within the i18n dir.

Comment: @Shiro did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Bit shorter:
``language: { noResults: () => "No Results Found (modified)",}, ``

Answer (score 49):

Probably, you have to add the script for the language you want to use. Something like this:

```
<script src="select2/js/i18n/pt-BR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then you can set the default language:

```
$(".select2").select2({
  "language": "pt-BR"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice and working solution. It should be added in the official select2 documentation! After some checks, the pt-BR.js can be located in any directory, and named in any manner, the important point is that at the beginning of the file, it returns `e.define("select2/i18n/pt-BR"...` to be recognized.

Comment: if your app is multilanguage all you need to do is to import the script language you need and select2 will take care of the rest according to current language.

Answer (score 15):

The option for select 2.5 seems `formatNoMatches`:

```
$('#search-select').select2({
  formatNoMatches: function () {
  return "No Results Found <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>Use it anyway</a>";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The **best solution** right now is to make use of **formatNoMatches** option.

It is clean and concise.

**Usage:**  you can pass either a string, or a function which returns a String to `formatNoMatches`

**Example:**

```
$('#search-select').select2({
...
formatNoMatches: "Nothing found"
...
})
```

or

```
$('#search-select').select2({
...
formatNoMatches: function () { return "Nothing found"; }
...
})
```

Ref: https://select2.github.io/select2/