# how to translate the result not found message of a select2 with laravel

Tags: laravel, select

I have a problem with the translation of select2 which is filled via an ajax call. I would like to translate the text result not found. If someone can help me it will be really nice. [image]

Comment: For your information it's inside of select2.min.js but @Aro's answer is correct.

Comment: Searching turns up some answers, did you try that?  Eg searching for "*select2 translation*" the first result is the official docs describing how to localise the whole plugin, or individual elements: https://select2.org/i18n ?  The 2nd result is an example of exactly what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306727/how-do-you-modify-no-results-found-language-in-select2-v4-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you modify "No Results Found" language in Select2 v4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306727/how-do-you-modify-no-results-found-language-in-select2-v4-0)

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, i search for that before asking. What @Aro mention i already test that but doesn't work, may be i miss something. I'll try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize not found text using property `noResults`

Example of code

```
   {
     "language": {
       "noResults": function(){
           return "My custom No Results Found";
       }
   },
```